# Gradle Cpp-Application not detecting gcc in windows

Tags: c++, windows, gradle, gcc

I am starting to get into c++ more and I have began learning gradle to use as the build too for it. I am using gradle's cpp-application plugin for compiling the code. However when I try to build it gradlew tells me that it can't detect gcc, my only installed compiler.

I have for the most part followed the guide on gradle's website (https://guides.gradle.org/building-cpp-executables/). That is where I came up with most of the code so far.

I have gcc from ming-w32 installed in my path correctly (I can run it from the command prompt and through make without any issues)

I am also using a gradlew install that was made with gradle 5.2.1

I am, for the most part, using the exact setup in the gradle guide.

```
apply plugin : 'cpp-application' 

application {
    baseName = "test" 
}
```

`^ /$Project/build.gradle`

This is the command line output when i run `gradlew assemble`

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileDebugCpp'.
> No tool chain is available to build C++ for host operating system 'Windows 10' architecture 'x86-64':
    - Tool chain 'visualCpp' (Visual Studio):
        - Could not locate a Visual Studio installation, using the command line tool, Windows registry or system path.
    - Tool chain 'gcc' (GNU GCC):
        - Could not determine GCC metadata: failed to execute gcc.exe -m64 -dM -E -v -.
    - Tool chain 'clang' (Clang):
        - Could not find C++ compiler 'clang++' in system path.
```

When I run the command that they say failed to execute in the same command prompt (`gcc.exe -m64 -dM -E -v -.`)

I do get output from gcc without any errors that I can see

If you are curious on what it outputs you can find it [here](https://pastebin.com/SE7UnmSy)

I would expect that the issue isn't with my cpp code because it isn't ever recognizing the compiler but it is fairly short so I might as well.

```cpp
#include <iostream>  

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  std::cout << "Hello World!!" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

`^ /$Project/src/main/cpp/main.cpp`

Answer (score 0):

By default, Gradle tries to locate a tool chain that matches your system's architecture (`x86_64`), but you only have a 32-bit MinGW

A workaround is to explicitly configure a 32-bit target in your Gradle script:

```
application {
  targetMachines = [ machines.windows.x86 ]
}
```